# Combinations of $1$'s and $0$'s in a circle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

Given a circle of $n$ numbers. $\forall n_i:n_i\in\{0,1\}$. $m$ numbers are $0$'s and the rest are $1$'s. I create $k$ pairs out of the $m$ $0$'s ("pair" means: "$00$") and $m-2k$ numbers on their own (means $m-k$ single $0$'s).

How many possibilities are their to arrange the $k$ pairs and $m-2k$ single $0$'s together with the $1$'s in a circle without any pair or single $0$ touches each other (touch means: they are direct neighbours)

E.g.: $10$ numbers, $5$ $0$'s, $5$ $1$'s, two pairs of $0$'s and one single $0$. A valid combination would be:

$0100100111$

The first ($0$) and last ($1$) are connected (like in a circle).

Thank you!

Comment: This problem would become infinitely easier to explain and reason about if you'd substitute $00 = 2$ and simply say that between any of $0$ and $2$ there must be at least one $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Do you consider circles that are a mirror image of each other the same? E.g. is 1110010 the same as 1110100 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are $n-m$ $1$'s, $k$ pairs $00$ and $m-2k$ singles $0$. First arrange all the $1$'s in a circle. Now there are $n-m$ spaces between $1$'s that will either have nothing, a single $0$ or a pair $00$ in them. Out of the $n-m$ spaces we first choose $k$ for the pairs and then out of the remaining $n-m-k$ (still empty) spaces we choose $m-2k$ for the singles. We counted each combination $n-m$ times (we can start at any of the $1$'s). Hence, the number of combinations is
$$
\frac{1}{n-m}\binom{n-m}{k}\binom{n-m-k}{m-2k}.
$$

Comment: Hey Vincent, thank you for your great explanation and formula. But you need to multiply the whole expression by $n$, don't you? Otherwise I get wrong results for $k=0$.

Comment: Are you talking about the case where the mirror images are the same or where they are not?

Comment: I'm talking about the case, where the mirror images are not the same.

Comment: Ok, but you consider 1110 and 1101 the same right? Because they are rotations of each other? If so, then the case $k=0$, $m=1$ should give $1$ right? Which it does.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Yes, it gives 1. But I'm interpreting all rotations as codes. The "circle condition" should also hold for the first and last number.

Comment: It does. Note that I am taking the number of spaces where a $0$ or $00$ can go as the same as the number of $1$'s. This means there is always a $1$ between spaces. For example, if we have five $1$'s, then it looks like this: $1$_$1$_$1$_$1$_$1$_. Clearly, whatever you insert for the _ the "circle condition" is satisfied.